# How to draw a linear regression line in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I saw other libraries support this but there is very little data for Chart.js. Can anybody indicate me the way to start with a regression line for my graph? This is my code so far:

```
var datiedu3 = {"labels": ['ok'],
          "datasets": [{label: 'EEE',
                        data: datoa ,

                        backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        showLine: false}] 
           };

function grafo2(dati, opzioni) {
  var grafoline = document.getElementById('Chartline').getContext('2d');
  new Chart(grafoline, {type: 'scatter',data: dati, options: opzioni});
};
// display the data used in dataset[0]:
console.log(datiedu3.datasets[0].data)
grafo2(datiedu3)
```

I figured I had to create another dataset with a line graph, and put my equation there, but I don't know how to do it and I'm a bit lost.

My whole code is here [codepen](https://codepen.io/dreamtheater96/pen/ZEGvRVj)

Comment: I guess one way is to plot the points of your regression line and store them all in the dataset ?

Comment: that's true, I tried, but the code I used to plot these points doesn't output any line! you can check it [here](https://codepen.io/dreamtheater96/pen/dyoJErb)

Comment: your `lr` object doesn't return any points.

Comment: your `yData` object has empty strings in the positions you should have numbers

Comment: same for `xData` that contains `Infinity` and `NaN`. And in the `linearRegression` function, you are summing and multiplying without a care in the world

Comment: whoops, I didn't notice I had to cut those values out... I still don't know how to do it though

Comment: trying to learn from the problem and the solution, i think the separate x and yData sort might break their linkage, so i'd suggest: const datoa = myJSON.map(
 itm=>({
  x: (itm['Value 1']+itm['Value 2'])/itm['numero_di_scuole'],
  y: itm['PUNTEGGIOSCUOLA1516']
 })
);

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I typically use  the [regression package](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/regression).

First, add the [package](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/regression@2.0.1/dist/regression.min.js) as an external script.
Second, clean your data. Just basic checks here:

```
const clean_data = datoa
    .filter(({ x, y }) => {
      return (
        typeof x === typeof y &&  // filter out one string & one number
        !isNaN(x) &&              // filter out `NaN`
        !isNaN(y) &&
        Math.abs(x) !== Infinity && 
        Math.abs(y) !== Infinity
      );
    })
    .map(({ x, y }) => {
      return [x, y];             // we need a list of [[x1, y1], [x2, y2], ...]
    });
```

Then run

```
const my_regression = regression.linear(
  clean_data
);
```

The result will be something like:

```
{
  'points': [[4,3.79],[4.75,3.83],[5.5,3.87],.....],
  'equation': [0.05,3.59],
  'r2': 0.26,
  'string': 'y = 0.05x + 3.59'
}
```

Done. We've got our [x,y] points. So transform the linear regression points into something that chartjs can render:

```
const useful_points = my_regression.points.map(([x, y]) => {
    return y;    
    // or {x, y}, depending on whether you just want y-coords for a 'linear' plot
    // or x&y for a 'scatterplot'
})
```

You can add these points either as

- another line chart dataset
- or with an [annotation plugin](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation).

Comment: The regression package Joe suggested works great for me. Can someone help me figure out how to get statistical significance (P value) from that regression test? Thank you!